# How can I obtain a String from a Byte() without mangling its binary contents?

Tags: vb.net, string

I have a language that generally contains serialised data messages in a human-readable format, but some productions within the language contain verbatim raw, binary data.

My parser uses `String` for its buffer since that seems to be the easiest thing to work with. However the data is read from a network socket into an array of `Byte`.

Now, I'm trying to connect the dots between `Byte()` and `String`:

```
' data as Byte()
' count as Integer
' buffer as String

buffer += System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, count)
```

But my initial assumption that an ASCII encoding would just leave my bytes alone turned out to be invalid; any bytes with a value that doesn't fit into the 7-bit model was translated into `'?'`.

So then I thought about using a single-byte "Unicode" encoding that should leave my bytes alone but also allow values throughout the 8-bit range:

```
' data as Byte()
' count as Integer
' buffer as String

Dim enc = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
buffer += enc.GetString(data, 0, count)
```

But my data is still mangled. I haven't actually been able to deduce yet *precisely* how the data is being mangled, but I do know that the length of the data is changing, indicating that the bytes are not being left verbatim.

**So how can I obtain a `String` whose contents are just a verbatim copy of the bytes from my `Bytes()` input?**

Comment: How did you encode the bytes in the first place?

Comment: @JaredPar: No text encoding. The bytes in question are binary. (Though the human-readable sections of the incoming data stream are ASCII.) I want to get a `String` from a `Byte()` whilst maintaining this encoding-agnosticism. Perhaps VB.NET doesn't support this?

Comment: you need to know a bit about encoding in order to decode properly so it can't be truly agnostic (unless you encode the encoding into the byte stream itself).  It sounds like possible you're looking past the human readable content and into the non-readable portion. Do you have a format set for the `byte()` ?

Comment: @JaredPar: I'm absolutely looking into the non-readable portion, and I want to. That's why I want to maintain this encoding-agnosticism. I just want `String` to stop caring about encoding and be a nice automatically-resizing array of bytes for me.

Comment: I'm almost sure now that the solution is to not use `String`, since I found out that it has an inherent encoding... unlike C++'s `std::string` which is just a bunch of bytes but which provides things like resize capability and substring functions. I thus need to find a good equivalent to _that_ in VB.NET. I might abandon this question and repost.. maybe

Comment: You may want to look at `List(Of Byte)`.  It's the rough equivalent of `std::vector<byte>` and probably closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: @JaredPar: Looks like that's going to be my solution. Feel free to post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on our comment discussion it seems like you want to see the `Byte` instances in the abscence of an encoding.  If this is the case you should consider using `List(Of Byte)` instead of `String`

Comment: Indeed; my not realising that the .NET `String` type is encoding-aware was the root cause of the whole problem. Thus the best solution is to use summat else throughout the entire parser, despite losing the easy substring search operations that `String` provides. This is now done and is working well. Thanks!